# Can SCOM monitor for a SQL server stack dump?

Tags: sql-server, stack, system, dump

This is my first foray into the world of StackOverflow, so hopefully I provide you with enough information here.

I'm an intern at my company and the boss has assigned me the task of investigating whether or not System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) can monitor for a SQL Server stack dump. Is this possible?

I was thinking of using a query to raise some sort of event in the Windows Application log. Then I could have SCOM monitor the Windows App log for stack dumps and then raise an alarm. Here is the query:

```
--To view SQL Server error logs in SQL Server 2005 / 2008 / 2008R2
DECLARE @HOURS INT
SET @HOURS = 24

CREATE TABLE #ErrorLog
(LogDate DateTime, ProcessInfo Varchar(50),
[Text] Varchar(4000))

INSERT INTO #ErrorLog
EXEC sp_readerrorlog

DELETE FROM #ErrorLog
WHERE LogDate < CAST(DATEADD(HH,-@HOURS,
GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(23))

SELECT * FROM #ErrorLog 

DROP TABLE #ErrorLog
```

I know this query won't do what I want it to, but maybe it's a starting point.